# duplicate image slideshow in fancybox

Tags: fancybox

dI have set a Fancybox to be opened using a Hotspot.
There are three images that I would like have as a slideshow but when I've done this the first image appears three times. So the sequence of the slideshow is photo1, photo1, photo1, photo2, photo3.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox5")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox();
  });
</script>

<a class="fancybox5" href="#inline5"><area shape="poly" coords="704,113,688,262,835,286,859,132" href="#" alt="Pics" />
<div id="inline5" style="width:100%;display: none;">
  <a class="fancybox5" href="media/photo1.jpg"><img src="media/photo1.jpg" width="400" height="500" /></a>
  <div class="hidden">
  <a class="fancybox5" href="media/photo2.jpg"><img src="media/photo2.jpg" width="400" height="500" /></a>
  <a class="fancybox5" href="media/photo3.jpg"><img src="media/photo3.jpg" width="400" height="500" /></a>
  </div> </div>
</map>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

w

Comment: You might want to clean up your code or create a fiddle.  I just tried to recreate this and you have an unclosed a tag, a closing map tag with no opener, and some other very confusing things.  It is worth noting that once I cleaned it up, it does work as expected.

Comment: First : I don't see you are closing your first `<a class="fancybox5" href="#inline5">` anchor. Second, if you are using images, you target them directly, you shouldn't target the container (`#inline5`) where they are located. Also you need to review your concept of how to use the area map tag.

Comment: Still having issues see http://laurellefkow.com and click on the picture.

Now with “ The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.”

Comment: I assume you mean clicking on the picture on that site?  If so, the reason the one picture won't load is because it doesn't exist.  http://laurellefkow.com/media/photo1.jpg  This link gives a 404 error.

Comment: Ah, my bad - naming error. THX.
But the other problem remains that I get a duplicate of the first image (photo3) in the slideshow.